# Python IF argument is true, following arguments ignored

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote an if that works, but ignores it's indented arguments. Here is the code:

```
else:
                try:
                    if grafo.node.index([int(va),int(vb)]) is True:
                        print("Arco já existe")                       
                except:       
                    Beta.criararesta(grafo,va,vb)
                    print(grafo.node)
```

Here is the class called:

```
class graph:
v = 0
a = 0
ponteiro = []
node = []
```

There is no traceback or error message, but if i print the list, the arc is not inserted, so the if worked. But why the print under the if is completely ignored during execution?

This is the traceback if i remove the try/except and proceeds to insert.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python33/Archive/PythonGrafos/Alpha.py", line 96, in <module>
menugrafos()
File "C:/Python33/Archive/PythonGrafos/Alpha.py", line 56, in menugrafos
if grafo.node.index([int(va),int(vb)]):
ValueError: [0, 1] is not in list
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`is` does not test for boolean equality, it tests for object identity. `index` returns integers, and no integer is object identical to the boolean constant `True`.

If you just want to test whether the return value of `index` evaluates to `True` in a boolean context, use:

```
if grafo.node.index([int(va),int(vb)]):
```

This still has problems, because `index` will return 0 for the first element of the list, and that's considered `False`. Catching the exception is the best way to use `index` to test for list membership. You don't need to put it in an `if` at all. Note that `index` is not the right tool to test for list membership if you don't care about the value's index. But this is what it would look like if you did:

```
try:
    i = grafo.node.index([int(va), int(vb)])
except ValueError:
    Beta.criararesta(grafo,va,vb)
    print grafo.node
    # maybe assign i to something useful here, or None, depending on what you're doing with it
else:
    print("Arco já existe")
```

Also, blanket `except`s are a bad idea. That'll prevent you from seeing serious errors. If you're just trying to catch the `ValueError` raised by the `index` method when the value is not in the list, only catch that exception:

```
except ValueError:
    Beta.criararesta(grafo,va,vb)
```

When you're working with a method that might reasonably throw an exception on normal input, it's also wiser to perform any other calculations outside the `try/except` pair. In this case, `int` can raise `ValueError` if, say, `va` or `vb` can't be converted to an integer. That would make the code follow the insertion case, which is wrong. Better would be:

```
iva = int(va)
ivb = int(vb)
try:
    i = grafo.node.index([iva, ivb])
except ValueError:
    Beta.criararesta(grafo, va, vb) # or possibly (grafo, iva, ivb), depends on the implementation
```

Finally, you should just use the `in` operator instead of `index` unless you actually need the list index, which in this code snippet you don't:

```
if [int(va),int(vb)] in grafo.node:
    print("Arco já existe")
else:
    Beta.criararesta(grafo,va,vb)
    print grafo.node
```

Comment: I tried changing my if to the one you mentioned, and the same execution happens. It does not insert if the arc has already been inserted, but also doesn't print as well.

Comment: Is `node` a standard Python list?

Comment: It's a standard 2 dimensional python list.

Answer (score 4):

`list.index` either returns the index or raises an exception. You're checking to see if the result is `True`: a singleton object - which an integer value never will be, so the `if` clause will never be true.

Comment: The if is working, because when i insert an arc, say (0,1). it goes straight into the except and print the arc. When i try to insert the same arc again, it does not insert, but the print also doesn't work. If i insert a different arc, it will print the old ones, and the repeted one won't be there. So it's working but ignoring the print.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if the `grafo.node.index` function does not return True. My best guess, according to your code, is that it returns an index of some array if the numbers exist in it, otherwise it raises an exception (is that why you wrote `except`?).

Try the following code to know why your `if` doesn't enter:

```
if grafo.node.index([int(va),int(vb)]) is True:
    print("Arco já existe")
else:
    print("Didn't enter if, got {}".format(grafo.node.index([int(va),int(vb)])))
```

Also, note that `if f() is True:` is very restrictive, the function MUST return `True`. You can use `if f():` instead, and it will evaluate as true for any number higher than 0, any non-empty string, any non-empty list etc.